# How to clear or remove the previous data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The below is my piece of codes what I want is there I have 2 option **male** and **female**  once the male clicked the ages show successfully but one the female clicked I want to remove the male and show the female age range?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#age").hide();

        });

        var gender = '';
        var age = '';

        $(".gender").click(function(e) {
            $("#age").show();
            $(".gender").removeClass('selectedGender');
            $(this).addClass('selectedGender');
            //           
        });


        $(".age-button").click(function(e) {
            age = $(this).val();
            gender = $('.selectedGender').attr('data-gender');
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your full code?

Comment: No this is not my full codes i cant paste all codes

Comment: Can i show you full code with html ?

Comment: If you can edit your question, and provide a minimal working example with the code, that will help others to understand and answer your query.

Comment: @Tushar i cant add more than that

Comment: use hide() to hide male age div and show() female age div

Comment: Please provide us with some more code so that we can understand your problem correctly.Thanks

Comment: how do you think that we will be able to help without complete example. You must show how you are trying to implement this scenario? include the demo as well of your html.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of `selected` radio button and can `compare` value of it and display `div` according to that .i.e :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#age").hide();
  $("#age1").hide();
  var gender = '';
  var age = '';

  $(".gender").click(function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    //if male radio is selected
    if (value == "Male") {
      //hidding female age range
      $("#age1").hide();
      //show male age range  
      $("#age").show();
      $(".gender").removeClass('selectedGender');
      $(this).addClass('selectedGender');
    } else {
    //hide male age range
      $("#age").hide();
      //show female age range
      $("#age1").show();
      $(".gender").removeClass('selectedGender');
      $(this).addClass('selectedGender');

    } //           
  });


  $(".age-button").click(function(e) {
  
    age = $(this).val();

    gender = $('.selectedGender').attr('data-gender');

    console.log(gender);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" class="gender" value="Male" name="radios" data-gender="12">Male
<input type="radio" class="gender" value="Female" name="radios" data-gender="13">Female <br/>
<input type="button" class="age-button" value="Click Me !" />
<div id="age">Something Male</div>
<div id="age1">Something Female</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to use radio button i use imges for each gender. If i click male it should display and when click in female the male should disappear and female displays. Actually i m using same div for both genders but different data for the value .

Comment: <!--Category of gender -->
        <div class="row gender-g">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><img class="gender img-responsive" src="img/male.png" data-gender="male"> <br>Male</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><img class="gender img-responsive" src="img/female.jpg" data-gender="female"><br>Female</div>
        </div>